# Use 2D array in a function C++

Tags: c++

I need to use a square 2D array (arr[n][n]) in a C++ void function that creates a latin square but the requirement is that the size of n is not given at the start of program. The user has to input the size of array. Example of my code (that is failing):

```
    int n;
    void arrayz(int n , int arr[][])
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
                {
                    for (int e = 1; e <= n; e++)
                    {
                        arr[i][k] = e;
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    int main()
    {
            int arr[n][n];
            cin >> n;
            void arrayz (n, arr[n][n])
    }
```

Please help me with this problem!

Comment: It's usually courteous to say how exactly the code is failing, and post any relevant errors.

Comment: `int arr[n][n];` isn't valid c++.

Comment: You need to allocate it dynamically with a call to a function like malloc()

Comment: @GiorgioGambino Better is to advise `std::vector` in such case.

Comment: well, the third loop does nothing in effect - each cell in the array will be filled with `n`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code, and it's unclear if you're just trying to get your work done for you, so I'll try a pedagogical approach:

1. As stated, if you want the array size to be user input, that is dynamically allocate, you need the malloc function. Than your arr variable is defined as a `int**`, and then you allocate space for it.
2. When calling a function you don't write the return type (void in last line)
3. When sending an array c style, just send the address - the array name in this case (arr, no [][]).
4. When defining a multidimensional array as a function argument, you must submit the first size at least. You don't know it though, since the user gives it, so just accept the pointer (int** for example).

I suggest googling a C tutorial if it isn't clear to you how to make these adjustments.

Comment: Thank You! These tips certainly helped me!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, your implementation is not possible, because `n` must be constant, which it's not. So here's a `<vector>` implementation, where `n` can indeed have any (valid) value:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void arrayz(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &vec){
    int count{ 0 };
    for (auto &x : vec){
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
            x[i] = (i + count) % vec.size() + 1;
        }
        ++count;
    }
}

int main(){
    std::size_t n{0};
    std::cout << "Type in the size of the 2d array: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(n, std::vector<int>(n));
    arrayz(vec);

    return 0;
}
```

If you then print out `vec`: (example run)

```
Type in the size of the 2d array: 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1
3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2
4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3
5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4
6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5
7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6
8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Comment: although that isn't a latin square.  try counting passes though the outer loop, and then `(count + i) % n` which results in a normalised latin square

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. Edited it.

Comment: I've been learning python.  It's even simpler (as expected with a higher level language): `def latin_square(n): return [[(y+x)%n for y in range(n)] for x in range(n)]` same idea though.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this in C++. However, you can do it in C since C99:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrayz(int n , int arr[n][n]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            for (int e = 1; e <= n; e++) {
                arr[i][k] = e;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n;
    if(scanf(" %i", &n) != 1) return -1;
    int arr[n][n];
    arrayz (n, arr);
}
```

This is C, not C++: C++ requires all sizes of array types to be compile time constants, which `n` is not.

Comment: I fixed the syntactic errors from copy/pasting the OP's code now, so there's no reason for downvotes anymore.